# Замена местами кнопок в ArrayList<JButton> в JavaSwing

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

Всем привет. делаю игру пятнашки на java Swing. В консольном варианте все работает. Начал переносить в свинг, начались проблемы. При замена местами кнопок в `ArrayList<JButton>` в JavaSwing уже в запущенном приложении не меняются местами кнопки.
По порядку:

1. создал ArrayList.
2. подключил ActionListener.
3. в методе

   ```
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       event = (JButton) e.getSource();
       System.out.println(event.equals(button1));
       if (event.equals(button1)) {
           int x = button.indexOf(button1);
           int y = button.indexOf(button0);
           button.set(x, button0);
           button.set(y, button1);
           x = button.indexOf(button1);
           y = button.indexOf(button0);
       }

   }
   ```

меняю в `ArrayList<JButton>` местами кнопки. 
Почему не меняются кнопки местами при отображении приложения?

Весь код игры

```
package barley_break_GUI;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Barley_Break_GUI_Start extends JPanel implements
        Barley_Break_Constance {

    static Barley_Break_GUI_Start start = new Barley_Break_GUI_Start();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    ArrayList<JButton> button = new ArrayList<JButton>(16);
    JPanel panelbutton = new JPanel();
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        start.createFrame();

    }

    public void createFrame() {
        start.createDimension();
        frame.setSize(width, height);
        frame.setTitle("Barley_Break");
        Image image = new ImageIcon("icon.gif").getImage();
        frame.setIconImage(image);
        start.createan();
        start.addMyListener();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panelbutton, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void createDimension() {
        Toolkit kit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension dim = kit.getScreenSize();
        width = dim.width / 4;
        height = dim.height / 4;
    }

    public void createPanelButton() {
        panelbutton.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4));
        button.add(button0);
        panelbutton.add(button.get(0));
        button.get(0).setEnabled(false);
        for (int i = 1; i < 16; i++) {
            button.add(new JButton());
            button.get(i).setText(Integer.toString(i));
            panelbutton.add(button.get(i));
        }

    }

    public void createan() {
        button.add(button0);
        button.get(0).setEnabled(false);
        button.add(button1);
        button.add(button2);
        button.add(button3);
        button.add(button4);
        button.add(button5);
        button.add(button6);
        button.add(button7);
        button.add(button8);
        button.add(button9);
        button.add(button10);
        button.add(button11);
        button.add(button12);
        button.add(button13);
        button.add(button14);
        button.add(button15);
        panelbutton.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4));
        for (int i = 0; i < button.size(); i++) {
            panelbutton.add(button.get(i));
        }

    }

    public void addMyListener() {
        ActionListener action = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JButton event = (JButton) e.getSource();
                if (event.equals(button1)) {
                    int x = button.indexOf(button1);
                    int y = button.indexOf(button0);
                    button.set(x, button0);
                    button.set(y, button1);
                }
                start.repaint();
            }
        };

        button1.addActionListener(action);

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponents(g);
    }

}
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что если бы речь шла про международные (стоклеточные) шашки, то в коде было бы две портянки по 100 строк? По поводу вопроса: в `actionPerformed` меняется `button`, но где в коде происходит перерисовка поля?

Comment: @Regent сделал перерисовку поля, но все равно не меняет кнопки местами

Comment: Перерисовка поля - это которая `start.repaint();`, находящаяся **вне** `actionPerformed`?

Comment: @Regent изменил и сделал внутри. не меняет местами все равно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение таким образом. может кому надо будет)

```html
package barley_break_GUI;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.util.List;

public class Barley_Break_GUI_Start implements ActionListener {

    static Barley_Break_GUI_Start start = new Barley_Break_GUI_Start();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    List<JButton> buttonList;
    JButton button0;
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        start.createFrame();

    }

    public void createFrame() {
        start.createDimension();
        frame.setSize(width, height);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setTitle("Barley_Break");
        Image image = new ImageIcon("icon.gif").getImage();
        frame.setIconImage(image);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        start.createButton();
        start.addButtonInFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void createDimension() {
        Toolkit kit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension dim = kit.getScreenSize();
        width = dim.width / 4;
        height = dim.height / 4;
    }

    public void createButton() {
        buttonList = new ArrayList<JButton>(16);
        button0 = new JButton(" ");
        button0.setEnabled(false);
        for (int i = 1; i < 16; i++) {
            JButton button = new JButton(Integer.toString(i));
            button.addActionListener(this);
            buttonList.add(button);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(buttonList);
        buttonList.add(0, button0);
    }

    public void addButtonInFrame() {
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4));
        for (JButton jButton : buttonList) {
            frame.getContentPane().add(jButton);
        }
        frame.getContentPane().doLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object source = e.getSource();
        if (source instanceof JButton) {
            JButton sourceButton = (JButton) source;
            int indexSource = buttonList.indexOf(sourceButton);
            int indexButton0 = buttonList.indexOf(button0);
            if (indexSource == (indexButton0 + 1)) {
                buttonList.set(indexSource - 1, sourceButton);
                buttonList.set(indexSource, button0);
            } else if (indexSource == (indexButton0 - 1)) {
                buttonList.set(indexSource + 1, sourceButton);
                buttonList.set(indexSource, button0);
            } else if (indexSource == (indexButton0 - 4)) {
                buttonList.set(indexSource + 4, sourceButton);
                buttonList.set(indexSource, button0);
            } else if (indexSource == (indexButton0 + 4)) {
                buttonList.set(indexSource - 4, sourceButton);
                buttonList.set(indexSource, button0);
            }
        }
        start.addButtonInFrame();
    }
}
```